# setState vs refs in react.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, reactjs

I created tabs in react and and now on click I have to change the class of the tabs the tabs classes may be as follows:

1:active
2:previousActive
3:alreadySelected

On click of a tab class become `active` and check whether it is selected before or not using `alreadySelected` class and `active` class from the last active tab is remove and if it is not `alreadySelected` then add `alreadySelected`.

Code of one tab in react:

```
var TabBody = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            class: 'tabBody tab activeTab'
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        a.tabBody = this;
        return (React.createElement('div', {
            className: this.state.class,
            ref: 'body',
            onClick: handleTabClick
        },
        React.createElement('span', {}, "Body"))
        );
      }
});
```

In order to change the class of the tabs I am doing in two ways and want to know which is effective. Code style one:

```
 var bodyClass = (a.tabBody.state.class).split(' ');
 var sleeveClass = (a.tabSleeve.state.class).split(' ');
 var neckClass = (a.tabNeck.state.class).split(' ');
 if (data === 'tabBody') {
     bodyClass.push('activeTab');
     var str1 = program.arrayToString(bodyClass);
     Interfaces.tabBody.setState({
         class: str1
     });
 }
```

Code Style 2

```js
a.tabBody.refs.body.classList.remove('activeTab');
a.tabBody.refs.body.classList.add('tabPreviewComplete');
a.tabSleeve.refs.body.classList.add('activeTab');
```

Which style is good for doing this and why?

Comment: Code Style 2 because you are using refs to access the dom element and react will store the virtual dom id on each so it would be faster and cleaner way

Comment: but react is all about states we have to update thing via setState. but using ref we are breaking its pattern

Comment: is there an alternative of this to alter the classes

Comment: yes my friend if we update any dom then we must follow the state but you are adding and remove the class of styles and for it's not require to put it in state because when you called setState it will call render funcation again

Comment: but when we use ref there is no need to use setState. it automatically render the component

Comment: yes when we use ref we don't need to use setState

Answer (score 8):

**The point of react is that you do not need to/ should not update DOM directly**. The idea behind react is that you render react components (virtual DOM), and that you let react figure out if and how to update DOM.

Changing classes using refs is a very risky strategy: Your component's state is then no longer in sync with actual DOM, which could bring you into debugging nightmares later on. So I would pose that Code Style 2 (even though it works) violates react principles.
One of the few exceptions for using refs, is to add a listener to a DOM component after it is mounted.

The react way is to put the classNames in state.
And do a `setState()` to update.
And let react do the DOM update,
which is very likely to be way faster, cleaner, and easier to maintain than getting refs, and changing classNames.

Comment: if we have more then one classNames then using setState all the classNames are replace by this new className so we have to use a huge number of ifelse condition. i.e for this first we have to get all the class name of the Component and then using ifelse condition we have to mannage setState. Using to many ifelse condition is not a good idea. for example if we have 5 tabs and we have 3 classes for each then we need 125 if else condition in order to use state

Comment: @wintvelt, would you please elaborate on this. I was under the impression that React would automatically cache & batch update DOM whenever there is ANY change to an element that has its 'getInitialState' defined?

Comment: I am pretty sure your code to manage 3 classes on 5 tabs does not need to have 125 if-else statements. You could put them in a dictionary inside state, like `return { "tabBody": "active", "tabSleeve": "previousActive" }`, and whenever 1 item is clicked, only update that one in state. Would need some more info on how exactly clicking affects your classes (was not quite clear in your post).

Comment: @Kayote The render cycle for each component is triggered whenever a) component receives (new) props from parent or b) setState is called. After that, react checks if and where new props and state lead to DOM changes and only changes what needs to be changed. React lives in javascript, so react needs you to stick to javascript and to give react the 'monopoly' so to speak on DOM updates of your component.

Comment: @wintvelt very well explained. +1

Comment: @wintvelt Wouldn't adding a class via ref be MUCH faster than setting the state? Setting the state causes the whole render() function to execute, where as adding a class only adds a class to an existing element.

Comment: @DavidC Maybe adding a class directly (via a ref) is faster than `setState()` in this particular isolated example (I haven't tested). But that is theoretical only: in real life: React bundles all changes (including `setState()` for class in this example), and the overall speed of this change + all other changes to the DOM is very likely much higher if you use React. Best practice is: if you use React, let it do ALL changes, including class changes. Otherwise your code will become a nightmare to debug and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

ref means you are using the actual DOM and setState means you are saying to react that please update the specific attribute of the component.
every thing is maintain by react.

On the other hand if you use refs it means you are doing every thing your own and react have no concern to your attributes and properties you are updating.