# React setState() call doesn't update UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, virtual-dom

I am learning React and am doing the `learnyoureact` module from NodeSchool. My understanding of React thus far is that you render React Components as virtual DOM and let React handle the UI changes (read from an SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33606118/setstate-vs-refs-in-react-js/33606978#33606978)). I'm assuming this is right.

Going off this, when I add data and call setState, the UI updates and adds a table row. How come when I call setState() and remove some data, the UI does nothing? I can confirm the data is being removed as I logged it into the console.

When I add 2 things to original table with 2 rows, I get 4 rows:
[image]

Then when I hit the `X` button and try to remove, the console shows that I did remove but the UI won't update. There's still 4 table rows.
[image]

I have checked line by line and later even copied and pasted to make sure. I pulled from this [repo](https://github.com/kohei-takata/learnyoureact/tree/master/exercises/prop_and_state/solution).

How do I remove the table rows if I shouldn't manually remove them?

Comment: Where do you call setState()? Have you in mind what is mentioned under "Notes"? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Comment: The client side code looks ok. Are you sure you haven't changed anything?

Comment: I call setState() in TodoList. The function that calls setState() is passed down to Todo and each Todo has a button that calls the passed down prop when the button is clicked.


I think I'm sure. I double checked. I uploaded to my own repo here:
https://github.com/Sticksword/learnyoureact_fiddling

What's odd is that I can add and the DOM updates but not deletion. Not sure why...